# Reset Aspire One (ZH9) BIOS password

Tags: passwords, bios, netbook, reset

I have an  Aspire One (ZH9) with broken hard disk and BIOS password... 
How can I reset it?

I thought about flashing a new BIOS but since I have no operating system...
What an I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it on my own cracking the netbook open and dissoldering and resoldering the battery back after 24 hours.
True horror.

Answer (score 1):

For $25, [this site](http://www.biospasswordrecovery.com/) guarantees BIOS password recovery.  If you are comfortable taking your laptop apart, these steps might work for free:

1. Turn off the laptop, and remove the AC Adapter, Battery, and hard drive.
2. You will need to remove the top of the case so you can see the motherboard, and access the location of the reset jumper (see the red box in the picture)
3. Connect the two points using Tweezers or anything that could conduct electricity.
4. Connect the AC adapter into the laptop, then Turn on the laptop by while keeping the two points connected for approximately 25 seconds
5. Restart the system. Press the F2 key to enter the BIOS Setup menu
6. If it still asks for a password, repeat the steps again, making sure you have good connection between the reset points

[image]

Comment: That's really it but... How should I open the case?

Comment: And I think this is for basic aspire one (http://laptop-717.com/how-to-reset-bios-password-acer-aspire-one-2.html) I have a Zh9 model.